# How is JOIN working, how can i use it correctly, do I even need it?

Tags: mysql, join

These are my tables:

```
category      (id(PK), name (varchar))

book_category (book_id(FK PK), category_id(FK PK)

book        (id(PK), name(varchar))
```

Now I want to create a query where I can get every **book** from one **category**

I'm stuck here, I cant figure out how I can get data from more then one table, I tried a lot with **INNER JOIN** but get SQL errors all the time

for example:

```
SELECT * FROM book
INNER JOIN category
ON category.id = book.id
```

So my question is how can I use the `book_category` table?

Comment: there should be one `category_id` field in `book` table. no need of `book_category` table.

Comment: i thought i had to create that table because of the "m-n" relation? i think i dont get here something, sorry =(

Comment: Hmmm... well it is many-to-many relationship - if one book can have multiple categories and one category can have multiple books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is an intermediate table which allows you to have a many to many relationship. If you don't have the second table you couldn't have more than one book belonging to one category whilst also having the ability for more than one category to belong to one book.

E. G. 
You have book 1, book 2, book 3 and category 1, category 2, category 3.

If a book can only belong to one category then you just have a foreign key in book which links to the primary key in category. E. G.  Book 1 and book 2 belong to category 2.
But what if book 1 belongs to both category 2 and category 3? You can't have this relationship with just the 2 main tables because there's only 1 foreign key field.
Your second table now links the two main tables so your book table has a foreign key to a book id in the intermediate table and your category table has a foreign key to a category id in the intermediate table.

Now you can have these entries in the intermediate table. 
1. Book 1 linked to category 2
2. Book 1 linked to category 3
3. Book 2 linked to category 2

Joining all three tables together will tell you that book 1 belongs to both category 2 and 3 and that book 2 belongs to category 2.

EDIT: adding an example to illustrate the point.

Book Table:

```
id      name
1       A Best Seller
2       A Worst Seller
3       A Funny Horror
```

Category Table:

```
id      name
1       Horror
2       Comedy
3       Non Fiction
```

Book-Category Table

```
book_id category_id
1       1
2       3
3       1
3       2
```

This structure says that book 1 belongs to the category Horror, book 2 belongs to Non Fiction and book 3 belongs to both Horror and Comedy.

The query, to find all books belonging to the Horror category is:

```
select book.name from
books join book_category on book.id = book_category.book_id
where book_category.category_id = 1
```

This finds every book name where the intermediate table has an entry for that book, belonging to the category with an id of 1.

You don't really need to join to the Category table at all unless 
(a) you don't know the id of the category you are searching for (and thus need to search by category name, which wouldn't be recommended), or
(b) you want to include in the query some information about the category (such as its name, which might be important if you aren't limiting your query to a single Category)

Hope this helps.

Comment: my basic problem was that i thought that the intermediate table automatically combines the category's to the books and that i dont get that i can use a book key multiple times like :
"Book 1 linked to 2"  and then use "Book 1" again for linking.

maybe someone is helping this

Comment: ok, i tried now alot but still i cant figure out which commands i should use :/ i have it like this now:http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?936406

Comment: I have added an example to my answer to help illustrate the point. I may have misled you in my original answer by saying you need to join to the category table. you don't actually need to join to that table unless you need to filter on something within it (other than the ID stored in the intermediate table) or being some fields from it (e.g. category name) back into your query result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add categoryid into book table as a FK.

So your query will be like

```
select b.* from book as b inner join 
category as c on b.categoryid=c.categoryid
and b.categoryid=@yourValue
```

Answer (score 2):

Make changes in the table structure:

```
category : (id(PK), name (varchar))
book : (id(PK), name(varchar), categoryid(int)) // categoryid is FK of category table
```

Then use query:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM book AS b
INNER JOIN category AS c ON b.categoryid=c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to use different `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.* FROM book b
INNER JOIN book_category bc ON bc.book_id = b.id
WHERE bc.category_id = {DESIRED_VALUE}
```